# How to display video from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html5-video

I have a simple app which contains a dropdown list of videos from a JSON array,

JSON data contains, title, id, buttons, position, URL

I want the user to select a video from the drop-down list something like this

[image]

so if user select e.g. travel from the drop-down list it should display a travel video which contains buttons in it something like this,

[image]

So far this is what I have tried

HTML

```
<div class="showme"> Show dropdown
  <select id="movies-container">
     <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
  </select>
</div>
<video src="" id="video">
      results goes here
    </video>
```

js

```
function PopulateDropDownList() {
           //Build an array containing movies records.

            var movies = [
              {
                "title": "travel",
                "left": 201,
                "top": 209,
                "movieid": "10",
                "movie_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
                "buttons": [
                  {
                    "left": 81,
                    "top": 51,
                    "start_time": 1,
                    "end_time": 2,
                    "buttonid": "10_1",
                    "btn_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]

            var movieContainerID = document.getElementById("movies-container");


            //Add the Options to the DropDownList.
            for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
                    console.log(movies[i]);


                    // movieContainerID.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                //Set movie Name in Text part.
                option.innerHTML = movies[i].title;

                //Set movieId in Value part.
                option.value = movies[i].movieid;

                //Add the Option element to DropDownList.
                movieContainerID.options.add(option);
            }
        }
        $('.showme').on('click', function(){
             $('#movies-container').addClass('show');
              PopulateDropDownList();

       });
```

Here is js fiddle I am working on : [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y59krhmn/3/)

What do I need to do to get what I want ? So far am stuck, any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of work ahead of you. It's not clear what you want to "do" with the buttons, you did not have content for them or actions. So I am not going to address that for now.

In regards to the Select, here are the basics I worked from:

- On Change, use the selection to get more details from data source
- Created a `<video>` container or update one from the selection

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lb7eh3zc/31/

**HTML**

```
<div class="showme"> Show dropdown
  <select id="movies-container">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
  </select>
</div>
<video id="show-video" style="display:none;"></video>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var movies = [{
    "title": "travel",
    "left": 201,
    "top": 209,
    "movieid": "10",
    "movie_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
    "buttons": [{
      "left": 81,
      "top": 51,
      "start_time": 1,
      "end_time": 2,
      "buttonid": "10_1",
      "btn_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
    }]
  }];

  function PopulateDropDownList() {
    var movieContainerID = $("#movies-container");

    //Add the Options to the DropDownList.
    $.each(movies, function(k, v) {
      console.log(v);
      var option = $("<option>", {
        value: v.movieid
      }).html(v.title).appendTo(movieContainerID);
    });

    movieContainerID.change(function() {
      var movieid = $("option:selected").val();
      var movie = getMovie(movieid);
      $("#show-video").attr({
        src: movie.movie_url,
        controls: "controls",
        type: "video/mp4"
      }).show();
    });
  }

  function getMovie(id) {
    var m = false;
    $.each(movies, function(k, v) {
      if (v.movieid == id) {
        m = v;
      }
    });
    return m;
  }

  $('.showme').on('click', function() {
    $('#movies-container').addClass('show');
    PopulateDropDownList();
  });
});
```

I feel it's better to break up things into functions. When the User clicks to show the drop down, it gets populated. Now the User will make a selection, and trigger the `change` event. Here we can determine what to do with that selection.

We update the `<video>` element via jQuery to now have the proper source and we then show it.

HTML5 does not have a way to add buttons to the video. You can control the video, start, stop, etc... but you can't add things to it. Now yu can create buttons and float them over. If you want them to appear at specific times, you need to watch the timer and trigger them to show. As I said, a long road ahead of you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Twisty thank you for the answer, as you said about buttons, using ur function, I have added  a function which passes button to video container, those buttons just links to another video or websites , in real video we have a video which contain a button in it (interactive video) , you just make buttons with position absolute, while a a video container position relative and then add opacity to here you go , thank you alot

Comment: Yes , exactly so if you assume in the video contain the similar button "next" you just add opacity to the next button and now the button inside the video will be clickable , as you now you need to specify the button exactly place where there is button inside a video , hope u got me

Comment: I have another thread am playing around with these videos and json for learning purpose can you please check this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655648/how-to-append-videos-and-its-description-from-json-to-dom-elements-in-javascript