# How to append videos and its description from Json to DOM elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html5-video

I have a simple sidebar which I want to display multiple videos from json, for now, I want just to show title and video from json something like this below.

[image]

Here is what I have so far.

```
<ul class="sidebar"> 
  <li>
  <h1 class="title"></h1>
  <video id="video_list" src=""></video>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is javascript

```
$(function() {
    var movies = [{
            "title": "travel",
            "left": 201,
            "top": 209,
            "movieid": "10",
            "movie_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
            "buttons": [{
                "left": 81,
                "top": 51,
                "start_time": 1,
                "end_time": 2,
                "buttonid": "10_1",
                "btn_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
            }]
        },
        {
            "title": "ecommerce",
            "movieid": "20",
            "movie_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
            "buttons": [{
                "left": 0,
                "top": 0,
                "start_time": 1,
                "end_time": 2,
                "width": '200',
                "height": '60',
                "buttonid": "20_1",
            }]
        },

    ];


    function getVideoList() {
        var title = $('.title');
        var videoID = $('.video_list');
        $.each(movies, function(index, dataValue) {
            var movie_title = $("h1", {
                value: dataValue.movieid
            }).html(dataValue.title).appendTo(title);

            var movie_video = $("#video_list", {

            }).html(dataValue.movie_url).appendTo(videoID);
        });

    }

    getVideoList();


});
```

Here is jsfiffle: [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n29y7j1L/20/)
I am able to display video titles for each movie but I am struggling to display both title and corresponding video as in json :(

What am I supposed to change to get what I want???

Comment: so create a video element and append it?

Comment: as you can see I tried that but its not working :(

Comment: I see no video element in the code above.

Comment: what do U meen u dont see video element ?? `  <video id="video_list" src=""></video>` ??? and in json there is video link : ` "movie_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4", `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is not defining each element. If you want a `<li>` for each title and video, you need to do something different. Consider making a function that builds the template for each container.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/e2q4kd13/12/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sidebar">
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var movies = [{
      "title": "travel",
      "left": 201,
      "top": 209,
      "movieid": "10",
      "movie_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
      "buttons": [{
        "left": 81,
        "top": 51,
        "start_time": 1,
        "end_time": 2,
        "buttonid": "10_1",
        "btn_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
      }]
    },
    {
      "title": "ecommerce",
      "movieid": "20",
      "movie_url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
      "buttons": [{
        "left": 0,
        "top": 0,
        "start_time": 1,
        "end_time": 2,
        "width": '200',
        "height": '60',
        "buttonid": "20_1",
      }]
    }
  ];

  function formatTitle(t) {
    var nt = t[0].toUpperCase();
    nt += t.slice(1);
    return nt;
  }

  function makeListItem(v, p) {
    var li = $("<li>");
    var title = $("<h1>", {
      class: "title",
      for: "video_" + v.movieid
    }).html(formatTitle(v.title)).appendTo(li);
    var vObj = $("<video>", {
      id: "video_" + v.movieid,
      src: v.movie_url
    }).appendTo(li);
    li.appendTo(p);
  }

  function getVideoList() {
    $.each(movies, function(index, dataValue) {
      makeListItem(dataValue, $(".sidebar"));
    });
  }

  getVideoList();
});
```

In your script, the video list is iterated and data for each video is sent to the function. The Function thenb makes a new `<li>` for each video. This will contain a `<h1>` element for the title and a `<video>` element. It is all then appended to the list container.

**Resulting HTML**

```
<ul class="sidebar">
  <li>
    <h1 class="title" for="video_10">Travel</h1>
    <video id="video_10" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"></video>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1 class="title" for="video_20">Ecommerce</h1>
    <video id="video_20" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"></video>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ur The GOD bro, thank you a lot, perfectly what I wanted

Comment: If you will have some time please check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675821/how-to-open-a-clicked-video-block-to-a-pop-modal

Comment: @user9964622 I will when I have time. My initial thoughts are that you need to really look at the overall design. Your sidebar should contain links to the videos and not the video elements themselves.

Comment: Some one help out it was just one code of line needed to be added , the videos contains links

Comment: Hii Twisty, can you check this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708370/how-to-add-time-line-to-html5-video-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You have to create dynamically new element for each item in the list.

**Javascript**:

```
var movies = [{
    "title": "travel",
    "url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
}, {
    "title": "ecommerce",
  "url": "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"
}];

var sidebar = $('.sidebar');

movies.forEach(function(movie) {
    sidebar.append('<li><h1>' + movie.title + '</h1><video src="' + movie.url + '"></video></li>');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sidebar"></ul>
```

Working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/omg0zkct/3/

Comment: Yep. I managed the same as you do , when I was searching for answer, nice solution though